# openpyxl formatting cell with decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

i am trying to set cell format to display 2 decimals, i need it to show 2 decimals, somehow when i use different office application to open, it gives mixed results, i am new to openpyxl (using latest 2.5.1), i have go through the documentation, setting the format seems pretty straight forward

what i have done for setting format is:-

```
ws.column_dimensions['F'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
ws.column_dimensions['G'].number_format = '#,##0.00'
```

not too sure am i miss out any?

For the attached image, it shows Open Office and Libre Office able to show the two decimals i needed, somehow WPS and MS Excel unable to show two decimals, a quick check on all the above format cell (through right click on that cell), Open Office and Libre Office is in Number format, somehow WPS and MS Excel is in General format

note: i have tried setting more decimals, e.g.: 3 decimals or more, still Open Office and Libre showing the specified decimals without problem, but WPS and MS Excel dont

[image]

Answer (score 7):

i have found a work around, which i need to set every single cell manually for formatting it to two decimals, seems working when using WPS and MS Excel to open

```
for row in range(1, rows):
    ws["F{}".format(row)].number_format = '#,##0.00'
    ws["G{}".format(row)].number_format = '#,##0.00'
```

Comment: This is not a workaround, the documentation tells you you have to do this: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#applying-styles

Comment: The second and the third line in your answer seem identical. Is one of these lines not necessary?

Comment: @Leonid, thanks for pointing out, supposedly is column F and G

Answer (score 2):

After doing the suggested, it still did not work for me.
Seems like MS Excel still sees the cell value as String.

So I tried to do a manual conversion of each cell before formatting:

```
for row in range(1, rows):
    ws["F{}".format(row)].value = float(ws["F{}".format(row)].value)
    ws["F{}".format(row)].number_format = '#,##0.00'
```

Gladly, it worked. I'm using Python 2.7.6. MS Excel Version 1808 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the round() function in python to round the figures there before writing them to their cells in excel. I would recommend adding the columns from excel to lists and then iterating through the lists using a for-loop

```
for i in list:
    round(i, 2) #Rounds each element of the list to two decimal places
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great tip! Worked very well for me!